# Problems installing NOTY with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install 'noty' in my website subdirectory 'js'.
I tried with ***npm install --prefix D:\XAMPP\htdocs\project\js noty***
In my php I have

```html
<script type="text/javascript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
```

I have a function for this and it's not working

```js
function alert(txt) {
    var n = noty({
        layout: 'bottomRight',
        text: txt,
        type: success,
        timeout: 10000
    });
    audioElement.play();
}
```

I don't really understand how, npm is working and how to use it.

Comment: `type="text/javascript src=` should be `type="text/javascript" src=`

Comment: My problems is that I don't know how to install the noty package properly with npm...

Comment: what error you are facing while installing it with npm?